# show hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds in php

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to take a total amount of seconds i.e. 972 seconds and convert it into this format:

minutes:seconds:milliseconds

I can't find a PHP function such as gmdate() for time that will help me convert it. Please help!

Thank You.

Comment: How do you plan to get miliseconds from seconds ?

Comment: I think the answer possibly lies within this Question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763668/php-convert-milliseconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds-fractional][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763668/php-convert-milliseconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds-fractional

Comment: This answer could be valuable as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37336227/1748266 (shameless plug...)

Answer (score 4):

This works for PHP 5 >= 5.3.0

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE));
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'));
```

From [DateTime with microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691428/datetime-with-microseconds)

Manual: http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

In the: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php you can use the format: date("i:s:u"); in PHP > 5.2.2,

i: minutes, s:seconds, u:microseconds and use a timestamp in the second argument to set as you were saying 972 seconds -> 0:972:0 But if you only want milliseconds I think you would have to  manipulate the resultating string with substr,...

Comment: that shows in that format, however it's not returning the accurate value of milliseconds. So I tried: echo date("i:s:u", 972); and it returns: 16:12:000000

Comment: Yeh i have this issue as well and have yet to find a workaround. :(

Comment: From manual: `Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds.` (might be added after this question)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$second = "123456789"
$s = $second%60;
$m = floor(($second%3600)/60);
$h = floor(($second%86400)/3600);
$d = floor(($second%2592000)/86400);
$M = floor($second/2592000);

echo "$M months, $d days, $h hours, $m minutes, $s seconds";
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.