# Cannot convert a date like yyyymmddThhmmss0+0000

Tags: php, datetime

I am getting data from a webservice but they send date with this format "yyyymmddThhmmss0+0000" 
and when i try to create a new DateTime from this format i get this error "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ..."

- example: "20161122T1030090+0000"

Does anyone have a idea of what kind of format is that, and how to instanciate a dateTime from it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your code?  What is your desired result?

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, i have a function that convert dates to a common format (Zulu). but in this case i get an error due to the extra "0"

Comment: My point was, you did not offer a complete question.  Please edit your question to comply with StackOverflow question requirements.

Comment: How much specificity do you need in your desired output?  Can you just truncate what is not needed?

Comment: This might be worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33691428/2943403

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), with escaping the `'\T'` and extra `0`:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd\THis\0T','20161122T1030090+0000');
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ;
```

Outputs:

```
2016-11-22 10:30:09
```

Comment: thank you @syscall, but is there another way without adding an extra 0 ? and is that a correct date format ?

Comment: @webhobbit Yes, use the format `Ymd\THisuT`, where `u` is the microseconds. It's probably that.

Comment: Yes @Syscall, it could be, and also it could be the "Leap" 1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise :D

Comment: Yes @webhobbit Maybe mentionned in the webservice documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but i have a meeting with them in one hour :) , thank you very much @Syscall (y)

Answer (score -1):

It is UTC format, you should convert it to mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS Format