# How can I convert current date and time in special time zone to decimal(16,4) in PHP

Tags: php, date, decimal

I want to convert the current date and time with special timezone to decimal(16,4) in PHP. 
That's my code:

```
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$myDateTime = new DateTime("now" , $gmtTimezone);
$time = $myDateTime->format('U');
```

but It returns a decimal(16) number in GMT and shows 1549351821 but I want something like that:

> 1549351821.1589

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691428/datetime-with-microseconds) question.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$myDateTime = new DateTime('now', $gmtTimezone);
$time = $myDateTime->format('U');
$formatted_num = number_format($time, 4);
echo $formatted_num;

  output: 1,549,355,258.0000;
```

Comment: No. I don't need that, I wanna show 1549351821.1589.

Comment: I modified the code

Comment: thanks. but It doesn't return the value of my special time zone