# strtotime drops microseconds from ISO8601 format, is there an alternative function that doesn't?

Tags: php, date-formatting, iso8601

When I do:

```
echo(strtotime('2020-06-16T08:08:18.339Z'));
```

`strtotime` gives me:

```
1592294898
```

Is there a function to convert date/time in `ISO8601 format` without dropping microseconds? (To a fractional number of seconds, similar to the one returned by `microtime(true)` function.)

PS. I'm using PHP 7.4

Comment: To clarify, `strtotime` by definition returns an integer of seconds, necessarily not having the resolution to preserve microseconds. You’re looking for an alternative parser that uses floats and/or milli/microsecond resolution?

Comment: @deceze sorry, yes, clarified in the answer itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime with microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691428/datetime-with-microseconds)

Comment: @Phil: No. If you read what I'm asking here, I need something that does a reverse of what you found there.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the insta-close. Didn't mean that. Re-opened now

Comment: What sort of result are you wanting here? A string, integer or float?

Comment: @Phil: `1592294898.339`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always with dates in PHP, `DateTime` to the rescue

```php
$str = '2020-06-16T08:08:18.339Z';

$dt = new DateTime($str); // or DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', $str);

echo (float) $dt->format('U.u');
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/ee9MZ

---

You could also use the [`DATE_RFC3339_EXTENDED`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339_extended) constant in `createFromFormat` if you're only interested in milliseconds but your question says *"microseconds"*.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Do I need to explicitly specify the format? I'd prefer not to. But if I was doing `DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601,'2020-06-16T08:08:18.339Z');` it was  always failing.

Comment: @c00000fd seems not. I've update my answer to just use the `DateTime` constructor. As for why `DateTime::ISO8601` doesn't work, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.synopsis (hint, the answer is severe short-sightedness)

Comment: If you were asking about using `format('U.u')` then yes, that is required.

Comment: Thanks, dude. And no, I was asking about the first parameter for the `DateTime::createFromFormat` function. So now it works the way you showed it. Thanls. I'm assumung that `DateTime` constructor is assuming an input string to be in ISO8601 format. Right? And as for the "severe short-sightedness" - it seems to be a middle name for PHP itself.

Comment: Also a quick follow-up. Sorry for asking, but I'm a low-level C/C++ guy. That cast to `(float)` doesn't lose precision to a 32-bit floating point number, does it? Shouldn't it be `double` instead.

Comment: @c00000fd I think all PHP float type are the same but I've also been out of the PHP game for like 10 years now so I could be wrong. Plenty of reading material here ~ https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: OK. Well, thanks anyway. I'll see if I can find it there.